# Fetch Record from mongo db based on type and ancestry field

Tags: mongodb

in mongodb records are store like this

```
{_id:100,type:"section",ancestry:nil,.....}
{_id:300,type:"section",ancestry:100,.....}
{_id:400,type:"problem",ancestry:100,.....}
{_id:500,type:"section",ancestry:100,.....}
{_id:600,type:"problem",ancestry:500,.....}
{_id:700,type:"section",ancestry:500,.....}
{_id:800,type:"problem",ancestry:100,.....}
```

i want to fetch records in order like this
first record whose ancestry is nil
then all record whose parent is first record we search and whose type is 'problem'
then all record whose parent is first record we search and whose type is 'section'

Expected output is

```
{_id:100,type:"section",ancestry:nil,.....}
{_id:400,type:"problem",ancestry:100,.....}
{_id:800,type:"problem",ancestry:100,.....}
{_id:300,type:"section",ancestry:100,.....}
{_id:500,type:"section",ancestry:100,.....}
{_id:600,type:"problem",ancestry:500,.....}
{_id:700,type:"section",ancestry:500,.....}
```

Comment: You will probably need to use multiple queries here to get the effect you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this MongoDB shell command:

```
db.collection.find().sort({ancestry:1, type: 1})
```

Different languages, where ordered dictionaries aren't available, may use a list of 2-tuples to the sort argument. Something like this (Python):

```
collection.find({}).sort([('ancestry', pymongo.ASCENDING), ('type', pymongo.ASCENDING)])
```

Answer (score 1):

@vinipsmaker 's answer is good. However, it doesn't work properly if `_id`s are random numbers or there exist documents that aren't part of the tree structure. In that case, the following code would work rightly:

```
function getSortedItems() {
    var sorted = [];
    var ids = [ null ];
    while (ids.length > 0) {
        var cursor = db.Items.find({ ancestry: ids.shift() }).sort({ type: 1 });
        while (cursor.hasNext()) {
            var item = cursor.next();
            ids.push(item._id);
            sorted.push(item);
        }
    }
    return sorted;
}
```

Note that this code is not fast because `db.Items.find()` will be executed n times, where n is the number of documents in the tree structure.

If the tree structure is huge or you will do the sort many times, you can optimize this by using [$in operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/in/) in the query and sort the result on the client side.

In addition, creating index on the `ancestry` field will make the code quicker in either case.